# Is there a way to set a debugger breakpoint on a Python inbuilt function like print()?

Tags: python, debugging, breakpoints

I have a large codebase I'm working with, and somewhere within it there's a print statement which is printing many '\n' newline characters.

I know I can set a breakpoint on my own code, but **is there a way for me to set a breakpoint Python's inbuilt print() statement?** Or any inbuilt function for that matter.

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Why not search *.py files for `print(` or `\n` or even both with a Regex using a tool like Agent Ransack or your IDE?

Answer (score 2):

Python can be patched at runtime, trivially, so you could add something like this early on in your runtime:

```
import builtins
orig_print = builtins.print

def my_print(*args, **kwargs):
    orig_print(*args, **kwargs)
    breakpoint()

builtins.print = my_print
```

Note that there are other ways to get bytes on stdout/stderr, e.g. [`sys.stdout.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) or [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) stream handlers, which may not necessarily go through a `print` call.